# Recursion depth problem while searching for all connected components

Tags: python

I'm trying to find all connected components from a Graph, but the recursion depth is to big. Is there a better way to implement my current code?

```
def get_connected_components(adj_matrix):
    adj_dict = get_dict(adj_matrix) 
    components = []
    visited = []
    component = []
    for node in adj_dict.keys():
        if find_component(adj_dict, node, visited, component):
            components.append(component)
            component = []
    return components


def find_component(adj_dict, current, visited, component):
    if current in visited:
        return False
    visited.append(current)
    component.append(current)
    for neighbor in adj_dict[current]:
        find_component(adj_dict, neighbor, visited, component)
    return True
```

Comment: Take a look at ```sys.setrecursionlimit()```, if you haven't done so already.

Comment: I did, but the data is huge

Comment: Try re-writing `find_component` using a stack instead of recursion. Also, consider using a `set` instead of `list` for `visited` to make the lookup faster. Also, do not seem to consider the results of the recursive calls at all.